# How do I do SUM PRODUCT with equation

Tags: excel

So I have column A, B, C

I would like to sum all 3 columns with the following euqation

```
    = SUM ( A * ( B / 6.1 + C ) )
```

Is this possible?

Comment: You mean like this? `=SUMPRODUCT((A:A)*(B:B/6.1 +C:C ))`

Comment: Oh, you can do that?  Didn't know you can write equation in SUMPRODUCT.

Comment: Why don't you Try it :)

Comment: Let me know if you are still stuck and I will post an example.

Comment: Yep, worked!  Thanks a lot

Comment: Glad to be of help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace `A`, `B` and `C` in your equation with `SUM(A:A)`, `SUM(B:B)`, and `SUM(C:C)`, respectively:

`= SUM(A:A) * ( SUM(B:B) / 6.1 + SUM(C:C) )`